# Problem with shading when using loop cuts

Tags: shaders

[image]What i did here is simple:
1: Create a cylinder, shade smooth, then auto smooth 30°
2: Insert two loop cuts in one of its side faces

After that i switch to object mode and i got a shading problem, a thick line clearly deforms the cylinder.
1: I want to know why this happens
2: Is there any way to fix it

thank you very much for you reading)

Comment: Basically, this is happening because you've added faces in a non-uniform way, and shade smooth is trying to make your object appear perfectly smooth given that geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faces 2, 3 and 4 make a flat surface. As you've shaded smooth, Blender creates a gradient between face 1 and 2 and between face 4 and 5, but not between the right of face 2 and face 3, nor between face 3 and the left of face 4, therefore face 3 has an homogeneous grey color and it visually creates this kind of stripe you show.

[image]

To fix it you can try the *Data Transfer* modifier, which will change the split normals of your object (split normals = normals that determine the shading):

- Create another cylinder (*Cylinder 2*) at the exact same location as your original cylinder (*Cylinder 1*), give *Cylinder 2* a *Subdivision Surface* modifier in order to make it round. Make it invisible (here I just display its wireframe).
- Select *Cylinder 1*, select the faces 2, 3 and 4 and asign them to a vertex group.
- Give the *Data Transfer* modifier to *Cylinder 1*, choose *Cylinder 2* as *Source*, *Vertex Group* > select the vertex group you've just created, click on *Custom Normals*, and select *Mapping > Projected Face Interpolated*. Result (you can apply the modifier if you're glad):

[image]

Comment: Amazing explanation, is there any solution to correct this problem while keeping those two loop cuts?

Comment: You need to move your 2 new edges, for example you can create a cylinder with a higher number of vertices at the exact same position and use it as a Target of a Shrinkwrap modifier that you give to your first cylinder, so that the edges stick to a circular shape

Comment: or simply move face 3 a bit along its normal

Comment: I tried it but it gets worst, any other solution?

Comment: @Ninja you can try the Data Transfer modifier, I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @moonboots )